# Rich Text issue with Java Web Application

Tags: java, mysql, richtext

Could someone guide me understand how to implement Rich Text functionality in Java based Web application. I am using Xinha for WYSIWYG HTML editor and I am having MySql data type of the text field as 'TEXT'.

I am able to get the Xinha WYSIWYG HTML displayed but I am not able to get the data saved to database. The code that was working fine without using WYSIWYG HTML editor to save the data is not working anymore. Now when I try to save the data I am getting a NULL value in the database.

Could someone guide me how to get it done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: the html code is recorded correct in the database? If you go there and `SELECT` the records, you will see html code?

If so, maybe your view technology is replacing `<>` to `lt;` and `gt;`, so the browser is not creating DOM nodes.

Can you please tell us what technology are you using and what is the generated source code? (if has or not tags?).

Comment: there is a **correction**, the data is not getting saved to database either. The code that was working fine before is not working when I am using the WYSIWYG HTML editor to save the data to database, I find a null value in the database. I am using **JSP** as the view layer technology.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Please post your code. The one that is getting the request parameter and saving it into the database. Also, the piece of html/jsp code where your WYSIWYG editor is written.